# ld: file too small (length=0) file (in failed gfortran compile)

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

on Mac OS (Catalina)
the command `gfortran -o file file.f`
normally gives an executable "file"
But now I have a corrupted environment and I get

```
>ld: file too small (length=0) file '/var/folders/dz/qjjbfdzs663fd6jmv27hcz300000gn/T//ccZ1MxJv.o' for architecture x86_64
```

I reinstalled Xcode and gfortran (versions 12... and 10... ) and also the "Command line tools" and deleted Library/Developer/DerivedData, and yet the problem persists. There are suggestions on this site wrt this problem involving an Xcode "Clean", but I typically do not invoke Xcode explicitly (I work in a Terminal window issuing command lines.) I am not seeing how to direct Xclass it to my "Project" per se so as to "Clean".

I was also unable to find the file above: it's not seen in ...T/ directory, or (T// whatever that means).

For what it's worth - attempting to compile and link and ld any .f program now gives this fatal error, each with a different ...T..// file.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. How did you reinstall gfortran? How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: I installed gfortran 10.2 for Catalina from...https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases. I installed Xcode from..https://developer.apple.com/download/more/... I am not sure where I got the original gfortran install. I am happy to start from scratch with the best versions if it helps.

Comment: Try homebrew, many people who come here use it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I find it really tricky to use `XCode` and `gfortran` from ready to use installers. I don't say it's always broken, but many times I have faced some sort of issues.

Instead, I suggest to install everything from the sources. Take a look here:

Installing `GNU` based chain on `macOS`

https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/

Then, you can easily maintain it using modules

https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

I know it's more time consuming comparing to `brew` or some other tools, but I have never experience issues with compilation, linking, etc. while using the whole chain built from sources.

Comment: To try to start "clean" with fortran, I have now uninstalled the previous version of gfortran. But I am not so sure I understand well the next steps to start fresh. Before installing gcc using the scritpts you pointed to, e.g, I am guessing I need to reinstall XCode and Command Line Tools. I do currently have in /

Comment: Yes, you will need `XCode` and `Command Line Tools` for building `GNU toolchain`. Once you have `GNU toolchain` in place, you can resort to `GNU` based tools and use only them (you will no longer need `XCode` or `Command Line Tools`).

Comment: In fact, there is another (alternative way). If you don't care whether you run natively on `macOS` or not, you can try different approach: https://github.com/mkowsiak/coarrays-docker

Comment: I have now uninstalled my old corrupt gfortran. Not so sure about the next steps to start fresh. I'll use the scripts you pointed to, e.g, > curl -L -O https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-10.2.0/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz But, I should rm -r my old gcc (v. 4.8.1) in /usr/local/bin/, yes? And even before that, I must reinstall Xcode and Command Line Tools (from Apple Store?). Should I rm -r Library/Developer/Xcode first? That's my plan - remove Xcode (and Tools? which are where?), Install Xcode. rm old gcc. Install new. Then I believe I will see new gcc and gfortran in /usr/local/bin/   Sound right? Tx

Comment: I will look at the docker stuff.

Comment: In fact, when you build everything from sources, you don't have to install inside `/usr/local`. Whenever I install `GNU` stuff, I do it inside `$HOME/opt/usr/local`. This way, I can completely separate my builds from the ones that come with `brew` or whatever else.

Comment: I followed the steps in the build for ...opencoarrays link suggested above (followed that link to the original site of solarianprogrammer... All OK until the "build", which crashed pretty quickly. The output of each step is here... stevelord.net/init_steps.html ... stevelord.net/config.html .... stevelord.net/make.html ... it ends with a whimper:....... config.status: creating config.h config.status: executing default commands make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2 ..........Error [2] seems generic. Are my error(s) blatant? Thanks!